# How to get right click menu when folder in column view

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I am using elementary OS freya.

How to get right click menu when the folder is in column view and folder is fully populated and takes all the space.

I got right click menu for list view by clicking on header.

I don't find any way for `View as column`

*Edit*:

I was able to get rightclick menu from keyboard key, but not from mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1203926) in the file manager.

In the ***list view*** you can click on the column header (the top bar, the one that says filename, size,...) to obtain the menu

[image]

...but for the ***column view*** such a trick doesn't exist.

Comment: I am accepting this as answer. Please update the answer once there is fix :)

Answer (score 2):

At least to create a new folder you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: It is to create new folder, correct?

Comment: Yes. I have specified that in the answer :)